# How do i get numbers from this string?

Tags: javascript, string

i have this string:

```
var s = 'http://xxxxxxx.xxx/abcd123456789?abc=1';
```

how do i get digits 123456789 (between "d" and "?") ?

these digits may vary. the number of digits may vary as well.

How do i get them?? Regex? Which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
'http://xxxxxxx.xxx/abcd123456789?abc=1'.match(/\d+(?=\?)/)[0];
 //                                             ^1 or more digits followed by '?'
```

Comment: The look-ahead match ("?=") is JavaScript 1.5 only, so for older browsers you might consider having a non-look ahead match of the "?" and just stripping the last character off the match result.

Comment: @Anndrew: yep, like `'http://xxxxxxx.xxx/abcd123456789?abc=1'.match(/\d+\?/)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]`

Comment: @Andrew: by the way, can you point me to a source for that? I see lookaheads described as far back as in js1.2 (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Well JS versions are a bit ambiguous (when it comes to understanding if a given browser version's interpreter runs a particular JS version and understanding how this all relates to ECMAScript), but it was from an arbitrary Google result and your MDN link is likely to be more authoritative. The specific page I looked at was this one:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var regexp = /\/abcd(\d+)\?/;
var match = regexp.exec(input);
var number = +match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the numbers always between "abcd" and "?"?

If so, then you can use [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp):

```
s.substring(s.indexOf('abcd'), s.indexOf('?'))
```

If not, then you can just loop through character by character and check if it's numeric:

```
var num = '';

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var char = s.charAt(i);
  if (!isNaN(char)) {
    num += char;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regex is the right answer.  You'll have something like this:

```
var s = 'http://xxxxxxx.xxx/abcd123456789?abc=1';
var re = new RegExp('http\:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\d]*(\d+)\?');
re.exec(s);
var digits = $1;
```